# Can't use function in object using this

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

Below is my code when I add eventlistener in my object:

```
this.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
    var canv = document.getElementById("some");
    myGameArea.x = (e.clientX - canv.getBoundingClientRect().left);//Look at canv
    myGameArea.y = (e.clientY - canv.getBoundingClientRect().top);//Look at canv
});
```

It works, but only when i use **getElementById** to find my canvas element and then use **canv** for my needs. But if i do this:

```
this.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
    var canv = document.getElementById("some");
    myGameArea.x = (e.clientX - this.canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left);//Look at this.canvas
    myGameArea.y = (e.clientY - this.canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top);//Look at this.canvas
});
```

Then *myGameArea* doesnt change at all and my debugger tells this: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '**getBoundingClientRect**' of undefined at **HTMLCanvasElement**.". I have declared canvas in my object before this part of code and i used this.canvas for a lot of other functions. So where is my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike normal variables, the value of the `this` keyword doesn't depend on where the function you're accessing it from is defined, but how it is called. In your case, `this` is being overwritten in the handler. A quick workaround would be the following:

```
var that = this;
this.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
    myGameArea.x = (e.clientX - that.canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left);//Look at this.canvas
    myGameArea.y = (e.clientY - that.canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top);//Look at this.canvas
});
```

Here we explicitly state the object we want to access, and thus don't need to use `this` at all. However, this is not considered best practice. The recommended way to deal with nested scope is to [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the function to the context you want:

```
this.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
  myGameArea.x = (e.clientX - this.canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left);//Look at this.canvas
  myGameArea.y = (e.clientY - this.canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top);//Look at this.canvas
}.bind(this));
```

Or, if you're using ES6, use fat arrow notation (`() => {}`), which doesn't create its own context, for the handler:

```
this.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  myGameArea.x = (e.clientX - this.canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left);//Look at this.canvas
  myGameArea.y = (e.clientY - this.canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top);//Look at this.canvas
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Appreciate that!

Comment: @ZaharZagrava Glad I could help. Be sure to mark the answer as [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) if it helped you, and best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

Within the callback closure, the context of `this` is the canvas element itself. Therefore, you would just use `this` to reference the canvas.

```
this.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
    myGameArea.x = (e.clientX - this.getBoundingClientRect().left);
    myGameArea.y = (e.clientY - this.getBoundingClientRect().top);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the callback function of `addEventListener`, `this` is no longer the same value that it was outside of the callback. If you would like to bind to the same `this` value you can use either `.bind(this)` or use arrow func:

```
this.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
  var canv = document.getElementById("some");
  myGameArea.x = (e.clientX - this.canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left);//Look at this.canvas
  myGameArea.y = (e.clientY - this.canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top);//Look at this.canvas
}.bind(this));

this.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  var canv = document.getElementById("some");
  myGameArea.x = (e.clientX - this.canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left);//Look at this.canvas
  myGameArea.y = (e.clientY - this.canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top);//Look at this.canvas
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much! But what (e) => actually mean? Can you send me any site or documentary please?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: arrow funcs don't have their own `this`, so `this` will still point to that outer scope